# Can directly upgrade ScyllaDB 2.1.x to ScyllaDB 3.x.x?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

As I have checked Scylla DB documentation and not found clearly where we can upgrade directly from Scylla version 2.1.x to 3.x.x directly.Is there any middle version upgrade required between 2.1.x to 3.x.x? Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process is not documented, because it was not tested
You can follow the 2.1 to 2.2 instructions using 3.0, and everything **should** work, but the safest path will be 2.1 --> 2.2 --> 2.3 --> 3.0.2

Tzach
(ScyllaDB Product Manager)